# We need to check for and capture a URL parameter that may on any page so we need a efficient way to do this?

Tags: cookies

We need to track some **anonymous** users coming to the site with a URL parameter, like "?utc=1234". This could be on any page though so I don't know what the most resource-efficient way to accomplish this is.

We are also using Cloudflare and Memcached so I don't know how this may affect anonymous users.

The use case is, upon a page load, to check if the URL parameter exists and, if it does, then save it to a cookie for later retrieval.

Comment: Sounds like a job for an event subscriber IMO.

Comment: Yes, but then you can't use page caches like the Internal Page Cache and Cloudfare. When the page is served from cache the event subscriber on the server doesn't run.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an event subscriber: https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-custom-modules/subscribe-to-and-dispatch-events